# Элeмент интерфейса switch, есть ли аналоги, не требующие 14 lvl API?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, есть ли в `switch` в **`support lib`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SwitchCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html).